# Upgrade to start Gitlab 7.0 after upgrade from 6.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, gitlab

I was running Gitlab CE 6.9 and decided to upgrade to brand new 7.0 version.
As usual I follow the upgrade guide, without any error during the process, but at the end, when I tried to start gitlab I got this error :

```
# sudo service gitlab start
Starting both the GitLab Unicorn and Sidekiq/etc/init.d/gitlab: 170: /etc/init.d/gitlab: script/web: not found
/etc/init.d/gitlab: 177: /etc/init.d/gitlab: script/background_jobs: not found
..............................Waited 30s for the processes to write their pids, something probably went wrong.
```

I checked to log directory, but I didn't find any error.

I'm using :

- ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [i686-linux]
- rake, version 10.3.2
- gem 2.0.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitLab issue 7163](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7163) now includes [that comment](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7163#issuecomment-46715103)  referring to [Robert Schilling (Razer6)](https://github.com/Razer6) PR: "[copy init script while upgrading](https://github.com/Razer6/gitlabhq/commit/9ba2e1873b9c6b972655a423fce6dd6aa4c2417d)" for the [`doc/update/6.9-to-7.0.md`](https://github.com/Razer6/gitlabhq/blob/9ba2e1873b9c6b972655a423fce6dd6aa4c2417d/doc/update/6.9-to-7.0.md) file (["Install libs, migrations, etc." section](https://github.com/Razer6/gitlabhq/blob/9ba2e1873b9c6b972655a423fce6dd6aa4c2417d/doc/update/6.9-to-7.0.md#4-install-libs-migrations-etc)):

```sh
# Update init.d script
sudo cp lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/gitlab
```